# Как вытащить данные из массива

Tags: php, foreach

Есть массив `$newtable`.

```
var_dump($newtable);

array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#12665 (5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_user"]=> string(2) "70" ["sum_chatl"]=> string(3) "100" ["chatl_history"]=> string(12) "purchase 100" ["history"]=> string(10) "1514601557" } }
```

Не понимаю  как вытащить значение history foreachем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это же обычный массив с объектами, просто обращаетесь к элементу объекта:

```
foreach ($newtable as $item) {
    echo $item->history;
}
```